# Magento Product1 shows In Stock in Website1 & Product1 shows Out Of Stock in Website2

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I've created multi website using different root category.
But added the same product in both website.

Product1 shows **In Stock in Website1**(default store) &

Product1 shows **Out Of Stock in Website2**.

help me to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: **It may be a configurable product,
where none of the associated products are linked to Website2** 
(or the associated product(s) that ARE linked are sold out, except a product linked only to website1)

Comment: this solved my problem

Comment: I've all simple product